# Adding a property to list<T> at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a `List<T>` that has properties for office locations and I would like to add a new property to each list item at runtime. Using 4.0

currently what I have:

```
//create json object for bing maps consumption
List<Dictionary<string, string>> locations = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
mlaLocations.ToList().ForEach(x => {
    locations.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
        {"where", x.Address.Street1 + ", " + x.Address.City + ", " + x.Address.State + " " + x.Address.PostalCode},
        {"email", x.Email},
        {"fax", x.Fax},
        {"href", "http://www.mlaglobal.com/locations/" +  Utils.CleanString(x.Name) + "/" + x.Id},
        {"name", x.Name},
        {"streetAddress", x.Address.Street1},
        {"city", x.Address.City},
        {"state", x.Address.State},
        {"zip", x.Address.PostalCode}
    });
});
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"","var locations = " + jss.Serialize(locations.ToList()),true);
```

what I would like to do is elimate `List<Dictionary<string, string>> locations` and just add the href property to the mlaLocations object. Or perhaps there is a better method to doing this all together.

Comment: Not sure what version of .Net you're using, but have you considered dynamic objects?

Comment: I thought about that but would that take up more memory than `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`

Comment: I'm thinking ExpandoObject, which is both a dictionary and dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous types should work fine in your case:

```
var locations = mlaLocations.ToList().Select(x => new {
        where = x.Address.Street1 + ", " + x.Address.City,
        email =x.Email }
);
```

Comment: thanks Alexei, I like this code better than mine, much cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

Use ExpandoObject and `dynamic`:

```
List<dynamic> locations = //whatever

foreach (dynamic location in locations)
    location.href = "http://www.mlaglobal.com/locations/"
      + Utils.CleanString(location.Name) + "/" + location.Id;
```